# API invites to facebook events no longer possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it currently possible to invite users to a facebook event via any API? 
Scripting language doesn't matter, I just want to know if there is still any possibility to do that.

I've searched the web for a while now but haven't got a clear answer. All the forum topics I've found that discuss this and suggest it's possible are years old. 
It seems it was possible before, but not anymore? 
At least the official Graph API reference says it's no longer possible: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event/invited#publish
"Publishing
You cannot invite people to events via the Graph API."

Is there any other way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: If the documentation say that it is not possible that means that it is not possible

Comment: With Graph API yes... my question was, if anyone knows if there is some other way to do it - with some other API or script.

Comment: No Facebook don't have another API that does it. Then it would be a link on that page

Comment: Not anymore it seems, yes. There was also the REST API before and it is still mentioned on developers.facebook.com, but the API docs have been removed. 
http://restfb.com/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest